# Category of accessible functors and its closedness

Tags: category-theory, accessible-categories

Is the category of $\sf{Set}$ accessible endofunctors right closed w.r.t. composition (as a monoidal structure)? Any hint on how to prove this?

I think that this is true if one works with finitary endofunctors (formula 4.6 of Adjunctions whose counits are coequalizers, and presentations of finitary enriched monads, by Kelly and Power).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\kappa$ a regular cardinal and let $\mathcal{M}_\kappa$ be the category of $\kappa$-accessible functors $\mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{Set}$.

1. $\mathcal{M}_\kappa$ is a finitely accessible category: indeed, $\mathcal{M}_\kappa$ is equivalent to $[\mathbf{Set}_{< \kappa}, \mathbf{Set}]$
2. The inclusion $\mathcal{M}_\kappa \hookrightarrow [\mathbf{Set}, \mathbf{Set}]$ preserves colimits for arbitrary small diagrams.
3. For any functor $F : \mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{Set}$, ${-} \circ F : [\mathbf{Set}, \mathbf{Set}] \to [\mathbf{Set}, \mathbf{Set}]$ preserves colimits for arbitrary small diagrams.
4. Hence, ${-} \circ F : \mathcal{M}_\kappa \to \mathcal{M}_\kappa$ preserves colimits for arbitrary small diagrams, and therefore has a right adjoint by the accessible adjoint functor theorem.

The problem is this: if $\lambda$ is a regular cardinal and $\kappa < \lambda$, then $\mathcal{M}_\kappa \subseteq \mathcal{M}_\lambda$, but I see no reason for the inclusion to preserve the right adjoint of ${-} \circ F$. (It's hard enough to understand what the right adjoint is!) Assuming that is true, and that is a big assumption, then it would be true that the category $\mathcal{M} = \bigcup_\kappa \mathcal{M}_\kappa$ of all accessible functors $\mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{Set}$ is monoidal closed.